# how to generate pixel data of an image

Tags: image-processing, pixel

I'm working on a video encoder having the part number ADV7391BCPZ. Now i have to generate an image using encoder. The FPGA is feeding the required input to encoder. I want to generate the pixel data of the image interms of Y Cr Cb format because, my encoder will accept only that form of input.

Now i request you to suggest the method to convert an image to its pixel data.

Comment: please give me suggestion

Comment: PLEASE GIVE ME A SUGGESTION SIR, PLEASE

Comment: Your question is not very easy to understand. You already have the resolution chart image so what are you hoping to get as your result? What have you tried?

Comment: the image should be generated by the encoder. I'm feeding the pixel data from FPGA to encoder. I want you to suggest how to generate the pixel data of that particular image

Comment: i cant give directly image input to FPGA, so i want to generate the pixel data for this image

Comment: I still don't understand. The normal way to *"get the pixel data"* of an image is to read the image using a library. Why don't you load the image with an imaging library and you will have the pixels.

Comment: i tried online tools sir, but no expected output is coming sir.

Comment: i want you to suggest how to get the pixel data of that image

Comment: Ok, but you have given no indication of what format the pixel data needs to be in (ASCII, CSV, binary, RGB/greyscale?), nor what languages you can use, nor what OS you use, nor what hardware (FPGA, custom hardware, PC, Mac) the program to extract the data needs to run on...

Comment: i want the pixel data to be in Y Cr Cb format, because my encoder will accept only this format of input. i'm using ISE 14.5 tool and spartan 6 FPGA sir.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please give me a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest way to do that is with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal:

```
magick z9mSc.jpg -colorspace YCC txt:
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 180,180,255,ycc
0,0: (255,156.098,136.955)  #FF9C89  ycc(255,156.098,136.955)
1,0: (255,156.098,136.955)  #FF9C89  ycc(255,156.098,136.955)
2,0: (255,156.098,136.955)  #FF9C89  ycc(255,156.098,136.955)
3,0: (255,156.098,136.955)  #FF9C89  ycc(255,156.098,136.955)
4,0: (255,156.098,136.955)  #FF9C89  ycc(255,156.098,136.955)
...
...
```

That tells you pixel 0,0 has YCC values (255,156.098,136.955) followed by the other pixels.

---

Or, if you want it in binary, you can do:

```
magick z9mSc.jpg YCbCr:image.bin
```

which will give you a file called `image.bin` with size 97,200 bytes because your image is 180x180 pixels and you will get 3 bytes (Y, Cb and Cr) for each pixel in the binary file.

---

Note that you can convert your image into its three constituent channels and lay them out side-by-side with `Y` on the left, `Cb` in the middle and `Cr` on the right like this:

```
magick z9mSc.jpg -colorspace YCBCR -separate +append separated.png
```

[image]

If you do that, you will notice that all the information is in the `Y` channel and that the other two channels are constant. So, you could save space and just use the `Y` channel in your FPGA and synthesise constant `Cb` and `Cr` channels alongside it. To extract just the `Y` channel, you can do:

```
magick z9mSc.jpg -colorspace YCBCR -channel R -separate gray:Y.bin
```

Comment: You still haven't said what OS you are using. **ImageMagick** is a command-line imaging tool - you will need to install it if it is not installed on your system. If you install an old v6 version, use `convert input.jpg ...` rather than `magick input.jpg ...`

Comment: sir, it is coming like command not found. Can you please suggest me any other way

Comment: You haven't said what operating system you are using. You haven't said if you installed ImageMagick. Or how you installed it.

Comment: I'm using mobaXterm software sir, since im using windows 7

Comment: i have installed sir but not working it is coming like unable to open the file

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and put all the information in there, including how/where you installed ImageMagick, what version, what actual command you tried to run, what the actual error message was.

Comment: please give me a suggestion sir

Comment: You have my suggestion - it was was to edit your question and put **ALL** the information in there so that folks can help you.

Comment: sir, ihve downloaded ubuntu and installed ImagicMagick 7, but there is an error no decode deligate for jpg. how to resolve this error sir. Any suggestion sir

Comment: please give me a suggestion sir

Comment: You need to install delegates then reinstall **ImageMagick** so `sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev libtool pkg-config` then `sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev` Then reinstall **ImageMagick**.

Comment: it is coming like unable to locate package libjpeg for second command

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be having trouble using **ImageMagick**, another option might be to use `ffmpeg` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i z9mSc.jpg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p image.yuv
```

which gives you a planar YUV file of 97,200 bytes which seems correct for your 180x180 image.

Comment: is there any possibility to generate the data in binary sir

Comment: the file generated having improper data format. Some foreign alphabets are used.

Comment: There are no *"alphabets"* in the file. It is pure YUV pixel values. Each byte represents a number between 0..255.